# Meaning of the word "mehr" in context

Tags: meaning

Can you please tell me what *mehr* means in the sentence below?

> Wir hatten uns schon eine Weile nicht **mehr** gesehen, also waren wir beide sehr aufgeregt über unser Treffen.

Without it the sentence makes perfect sense to me. I can't understand what meaning it adds to the sentence.

Comment: Compare to the english phrase "... not any *more*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"nicht mehr" functions as the negation of "noch". It expresses that a habit of meeting had been discontinued. Of course, this includes simple negation, but it adds a backgronded idea to it.